# why with float property text also not changing its position with the background?

Tags: css, css-float

i have this code

```
<div id="one" class="test">first div</div>
<div id="two" class="test">second div div</div>
<div id="three" class="test">third  div</div>
```

when i float the first and second div to left but not the third div, background of the third div comming upward , which is ok , becasue third div should be set as clear:both. But i want to know why 
the text of the third div is also not comming up becasue the text is inside the div.

fiddle link here http://jsfiddle.net/babu333/3KPxE/3/

Comment: Wow got me stumped. I mean I can see the element when I take a look at it in the google developer's tools, but the text just shows up wherever it wants I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

From my tinkering, it looks as though the floats are breaking the flow of the `#third` element, while the text within the elements is maintaining its flow, but being forced downwards from the floated elements.

Add the `overflow` property for more manageable results:

```
.test{
  width:100px; 
  height:50px; 
  margin:20px; 
  padding:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KPxE/7/)

When dealing with floats, I've found it's always best to add `overflow: hidden` to parent containers.

Comment: If you take out padding and margin, text of the third div will still be at the bottom of the first div

Comment: @user1906399 you're right! I'll keep tinkering and edit my answer if I find something

Comment: @user1906399 looks like I'm stumped too. The flow is simply being broken, while the text is retaining its flow. Floats can be tricky to deal with